# How do I turn off global gems for rvm?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I was following along a railscast, and was told that turning on global gems was good for a specific set of gems.  But now when I try to install gems I get errors.  So after using

```
rvm gemset use global
```

How do I revert this?

```
$ rvm gemdir
/Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
$ rvm gemset delete global
```

Read more about [deleting gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/deleting).

Comment: Worked for me as well. Have a project-specific gemset that was getting broken by redundancies based on the global gemset.

Comment: Thanks, this was messing up my separation of gemsets.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I need my @global gemset. But I need it disabled for sometime.

So my way it is just rename it:

```
$ cd ~/.rvm/gems/
$ mv ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/   ruby-1.9.3-p327@global_
```