# Trying to run compass create - getting Gemfile Not Found Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos, compass-sass

I am trying to get started with Compass/SASS with Foundation. I have installed ruby 2.0.0 using rvm and installed compass as well. I am using centOS.

However, when I try to run the following command:

```
# compass create emj --javascripts-dir "js" --images-dir "img"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:16:in `build': /Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have tried searching for some solutions but I have hit a wall.

Any suggestions or help is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: same here with Mac OS X 10.9. It was working just fine in 10.8. Basically any compass command ends up with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here. Taking a look at the backtrace, the "faulty" line(s) are these, from `bin/compass`:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
    require 'bundler/shared_helpers'
    Bundler.require :assets if Bundler::SharedHelpers.in_bundle?
end
```

Removing the `Bundler.require` line makes compass run flawlessly. For more information take a look at [this related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1424).

Answer (score 6):

In the past installing compass was a breeze, but I've been having the same problem over the past couple of days. At first I thought it was just an OSX Mavericks issue, but I've had the same issue on 3 different OS now.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659662/compass-gem-throwing-error) seems very similar to yours, however the answer didn't work for me.

In the past I don't recall ever seeing an @global directory, so perhaps something has changed about the way RVM installs? I did some hunting, [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151834/how-do-i-turn-off-global-gems-for-rvm), and tried:

```
rvm gemset delete global
```

I am now able to `compass create` without any issues.

I'm not sure what the global gemset is for and don't really care at the moment. I just want compass to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and found that I had the `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` environment variable set to `/Gemfile`. I'm not sure why/how it got set, but that was my issue.

```
$ bundle exec rails console
$ /Gemfile not found
$ echo $BUNDLE_GEMFILE
/Gemfile
$ unset BUNDLE_GEMFILE
$ bundle exec rails console
# ... it works
```